# Renting Vs Buying?? Define Function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, finance

A family has $100,000 in savings accounts. They seek financial advice to develop a ten-year housing strategy. The two options are: continue renting the apartment or take a bank loan to buy a property.

(a) Assume that they spend USD1900 per annum on renting the apartment and put their $100,000 savings in a bank deposit at the interest rate 2% per annum compounded annually. Find the family net worth (calculated as the money on the deposit minus the rent paid, in thousand dollars) after t years. Define the function frent : [0, 10] → R by allowing t to be a real number in the expression for the net worth.

(b) Now assume that the family takes a bank loan of USD400,000 for the period of ten years to buy a property worth USD500,000. This is an interest only loan at 5% per annum so the total sum to be repaid to the bank after ten years is $600,000 (one and a half of the original amount). Suppose the loan is paid regularly so it is described by a linear function, whose value at t = 10 equals the total sum to be repaid to the bank. The property value is expected to grow at the rate of 2% per annum. Similarly to (a), define the function fbuy : [0, 10] → R corresponding to the family net worth (calculated as the property value minus the loan paid, in thousand dollars) after t years?

FYI, I've never done Personal finance math (I have CS background), anyone wants to shed a light on this math problem? Have no idea how to approach this problem.

Comment: Well, the first question is quite easy. You just have
$$
\text{net worth} = 100~000 \times 1.02^t - 1900t $$.. do you agree?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Calculation

Comment: I do agree and understand the logic behind the equation, it is because of the compound interest. Well, how about the function frent? any idea. is it just f(nw)= 100000*1.02^t - 19000t where t = (0,10)??

Comment: The problem statement doesn't define very well what the function $f_{\text{rent}}$ is. The notation says "[0,10] -> R", which I interpret that something should be between 0 and 10 (maybe $t?$). So I would just answer the a-part by
$$
f_{\text{rent}}(t) = 100~000\times 1.02^t - 1900t
$$
The subscript is "rent" because in the b-part we are comparing to an alternative to renting and it will produce another function , $f_{\text{buy}}$.

Comment: [0,10] -> R includes 2 values in my case 0 or 10, 0 <= x <= 10. I am going with two values, thats what make sense in this problem to me.

Comment: @Transhumanist 
a) The net  value after t years is 

$$NV_t=100,000\cdot (1.02)^t-1900\cdot \frac{1.02^t-1}{0.02},$$ assuming that the payments are made at the end of each year.

Comment: can you please explain why you have considered the formula for annual compound interest? I've got the first answer given by Matti.

Comment: @MattiP. any idea about how to approach for part b)? thanks for your help though

Comment: @callculus Why does the rent have a multiplier of $\frac{1.02^t -1}{0.02}$ in your answer? To my knowledge, the rent doesn't grow any interest ...

Comment: @Transhumanist I´ve posted an explanation.

Comment: @MattiP. Yes, but the difference of the capital and the rent is compounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a) the family starts with $100,000$. This amount is compounded once. At the end of the year they pay $1900$. The net value after one year is therefore $NV_1=100,000\cdot 1.02-1900=100,100$. Now this value is compounded one year:

$(100,000\cdot 1.02-1900)\cdot 1.02=102,102$. Here we see that the rent is compounded as well.

And the second rent is paid wich gives a net value of  $NV_2=102,102-1900=100,202$. This was an iterative method.

In general the net value after t years

$$NV_t=100000\cdot (1.02)^t-1900\cdot \frac{1.02^t-1}{0.02}$$

Let´s check for $t=2$ if we get the same value as the value which was obtained by the iterative method.

$$NV_2=100000\cdot (1.02)^2-1900\cdot \frac{1.02^2-1}{0.02}=100,202 \ \checkmark$$

I hope it has become a little bit clearer why the formula is valid.

---

At b) the family has to pay back 10 times an annuity of $r$ which equals $600,000$ at $t=10$. Thus the equation is

$$r\cdot \frac{1.05^{10}-1}{1.05-1}=600$$

I take $600$ here since it is required that the unit of the function is" in thousand dollars". After the value of $r$ has been calculated the function $f_{\text{buy}}$ is

$$f_{\text{buy}}(t)=500\cdot 1.02^t-r\cdot \frac{1.05^{t}-1}{1.05-1}$$

$$\textrm{property value - loan paid}$$

Comment: Awesome! understood your point

Comment: @Transhumanist Nice that all is clear now. I would appreciate it, if you accepted the answer.

Comment: I´m still thinking...

Comment: @Transhumanist I´ve finished thinking. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are a legend!

Comment: @Transhumanist You´re welcome. I´m glad that´s all clear now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97221/discussion-between-transhumanist-and-callculus).